# High frequency transformer

Tags: voltage

Can I test a high frequency transformer (50Khz) on low frequency (50hz). If then what changes will occur at 50hz? can output voltage be same on both the frequencies?

Comment: No. You will saturate it. Look up/understand Vt=NAB.

Comment: can you plzzzzzzzzz explain it?

Comment: I deigned a step up transformer for 50 khz from 12 v to 220v and today i gave 12v (50hz) at its primary and i found only 26 volts at output. I have no idea why it is behaving like this. My teacher said that I can test my transformer at 50hz, the output will be same because frequency has no effect on it.

Comment: @AfraSyab Maybe your teacher wanted you to build an ideal transformer and you mistakenly built a real one.

Comment: Please observe that 12 V primary waveform during your test and report back.

Comment: can you please explain what happens when i apply 12v (50hz) at primary side and how?

Comment: You saturate the transformer and cripple the waveform. Measure it and see for yourself or you will never learn.

Answer (score 5):

You can test it at 50 Hz but the voltage you apply will have to be much lower than the voltage you can apply at 50 kHz. So, if at 50 kHz there is marginal core saturattion at (say) 10 volts p-p then at 50 Hz, you can use a voltage of 10 mVp-p.

If you put 20 Vp-p on it it would saturate too much and make the test results meaningless.

Other than that, Faraday's law of induction doesn't care about frequency when it comes to transformers, so it will work just fine. Don't even think about testing it at AC line voltage.

> My teacher said that I can test my transformer at 50hz, the output
>   will be same because frequency has no effect on it.

Either your teacher is an idiot or you didn't listen correctly.

Comment: I deigned a step up transformer for 50 khz from 12 v to 220v. I do not have any source right now to give it 50khz, i want to test it at 50hz then what will you suggest that how many voltage can i apply at primary side.

Comment: Try it at 10 mV peak to peak then at 20 milli volts peak to peak. If at 20 mV you get less output ratio than at 10 mV, then you are close to the saturation point and you need to establish this. If you have no idea how important this is you need to do some research.

Comment: +1 for relating voltage to frequency, and not mentioning inductance

Comment: @Neil_UK I can spoil it for you lol.

Answer (score 4):

The most basic [model of a transformer primary](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transformer) is that of an [inductor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inductor) connected across the two primary terminals.

[image]

The [impedance](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Impedance) of the primary inductor is given by

\$Impedance = 2\cdot \pi \cdot frequency \cdot inductance\$

From that you can see that if you lower the frequency by a factor 1000x, the impedance will also lower by a factor 1000x.  That means, for the same input voltage, the current would be 1000x larger.

That is why winny said that the core would saturate - the much larger current would cause such a strong magnetic field that your transformer core "[can't take any more magnetizing](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Saturation_(magnetic))" which causes behavior that deviates from the above impedance formula.

In practice, the higher current (provided the source can deliver) would likely [overheat and damage the fragile windings](https://youtu.be/1zrlOLrDuG4) in the transformer.

With all that said though, **IF** you properly understand your transformer model (especially [parasitic elements](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Parasitic_element_(electrical_networks))) **and** carefully control the input current, you can indeed perform simple testing of a transformer at "any" frequency.

Also **don't even think** of connecting it to AC mains unless you have a fire-safe environment, protective clothing, overcurrent protection and a high-speed camera for the sensational YouTube video that we would like to watch!

Comment: Dear I need your email id....

Comment: Don't over exaggerate what I said please.

Comment: @Andyaka roger, fixed .